# To identify ambigious local time using std::chrono

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

How to identify the given epoch time converted to local time(time zone UTC-8) is a ambigious ?

Example. Epoch time 1699173796 when converted to local time(time zone UTC-8) gives November 5, 2023 1:43:16 AM and for the same local time one more epoch time also available 1699177396.

How to identify this time ambiguity using std::chrono or using any other c++ libraries.

And once find it is a ambigious time, how to select the earliest/latest time for that

I gone through the std::chrono libraries not able to find any APIs

Comment: "_and for the same local time one more epoch time also available_": I don't see how. If you mean because of time zone changes (e.g. summer time), then you need to store the time zone together with the time. Aside from that I can only think of leap seconds as a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First convert your `sys_time` into a local time:

```cpp
using namespace std::chrono;

auto zone = locate_zone("America/Los_Angeles");
sys_seconds tp(1699173796s);
auto local = zone->to_local(tp);
```

And then convert it back:

```cpp
auto earlier = zone->to_sys(local, choose::earliest);
auto later = zone->to_sys(local, choose::latest);
```

It's ambiguous iff `earlier != later`.

To just tell if a local time is ambiguous, you can also use `zone->get_info(local).result == local_info::ambiguous`.

---

You can also do this with the higher-level `zoned_time` API instead, which has the benefit of not leaving a `local_time` floating around with no associated timezone:

```cpp
zoned_time original("America/Los_Angeles", sys_seconds(1699173796s));
zoned_time earlier(original.get_time_zone(), original.get_local_time(), choose::earliest);
zoned_time later(original.get_time_zone(), original.get_local_time(), choose::latest);
```